# Why suse root user connect oracle as OPS$DAEMON instead of OPS$ROOT

Tags: oracle

I tried to os auth root user, but even if I create a oracle database user `ops$root` identified externally, I keep getting failed logon error. So I `audit session whenever not successful`, and I see a bunch of `ops$daemon` user connection when I run `SELECT * FROM sys.aud$ WHERE returncode=1017;`

After I run `create user ops$daemon identified externally`, I success to connect as os user `root`, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сontact Oracle support site. Oracle N o t e : 9 1 2 6 0.1 - UNIX: CONNECT / as Root Fails With ORA-01017 and Works Successfully With Other Users

The sql*net driver will translate the 'root' user to 'daemon' as the code explicitly prohibits the shadow process being run under root id for security reasons.

```
 [root@db-01 ~]#strace -fo    /tmp/sqlplus.out sqlplus /

    SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Tue Oct 17 11:21:28 2017

    Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


[root@db-01 ~]# grep setuid  /tmp/sqlplus.out
18432 setuid(2)                         = 0
18433 setuid(2)                         = 0
18434 setuid(2)                         = 0
[root@db-01 ~]# grep getuid  /tmp/sqlplus.out
18431 getuid()                          = 0
18431 getuid()                          = 0
18431 getuid()                          = 0
18431 getuid()                          = 0
18431 getuid()                          = 0
18432 getuid()                          = 2
18432 getuid()                          = 2
18431 getuid()                          = 0
18433 getuid()                          = 2
18433 getuid()                          = 2
18431 getuid()                          = 0
18434 getuid()                          = 2
18434 getuid()                          = 2
```

The first 5 function getuid() calls return "0", but the last call  return "2".
"2" is the id of the "daemon" user.

```
 [root@db-01 ~]# grep daemon /etc/passwd
    daemon:x:2:2:daemon:/sbin:/sbin/nologin
    haldaemon:x:68:68:HAL daemon:/:/sbin/nologin
    [root@db-01 ~]# id daemon
    uid=2(daemon) gid=2(daemon) groups=2(daemon),1(bin),4(adm),7(lp)
```

The actual Oracle error should be seen sometime after the last getuid() function call. Because the return value from the getuid() function changes when logging into sqlplus as root using os authentication, the ORA-1017 error is returned.

This is not a Oracle bug: the root user is a special case on UNIX/Linux.

Comment: Is there more detail ? I searched 91260.1 and there is not much info.

Comment: I added the details.